¿Cómo usar las clases :hover:after en un mismo elemento?
Tengo el siguiente código


function hiddeQuestion(element) {
    let e = element;
    let div = document.getElementById("divDatos"+e);
    div.classList.toggle("active");
    let x = document.getElementById("answer"+e);
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
};
.divDatos {
    background-color: #a9d1f4;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #0177de;
    padding: 1%;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.divDatos:hover {
    background-color: #0177de;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    &.questions:after {
        content: '\002B';
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        float: right;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
}

.questions{
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.questions:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #045dac;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.questions:hover::after {
    color: white !important;
}

.active {
    background-color: #0177de;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}

.active .questions:after {
    content: "\2212";
    color: white;
}

.answers{
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}
<div class="divDatos col-md-12 col-sm-12" id="divDatos1" onclick="hiddeQuestion(1)">
        <span class="questions">
            ¿Pregunta? <!-- <i class="fa-solid fa-user-tie"></i> -->
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="container answers mx-auto" id="answer1" style="display: none !important;">
        <span class="answersText floatLeft col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <P>Respuesta</P>
        </span>
    </div>



Solo necesito una cosa y ya he buscado, lo he probado una y mil veces, adelante, atrás... Y no me sale el hecho de que el símbolo + se ponga en blanco al hacer hover en el divDatos 
Solo he logrado que se ponga en blanco al hacer hover en el span questions pero lo que necesito es que se ponga todo en color blanco. Incluso he intentado meter reglas de CSS dentro de otras reglas y nada.
Ojo, no uso ni voy a usar SASS o LESS, quiero hacerlo con CSS puro que se que se puede. También he leído sobre el uso de unas pseudoclases como @keyframes pero no logro encontrar la manera de hacer funcionar esas reglas 
Alguna idea? Se que esta pregunta si es bien básica 

El problema está en esta parte del código:
.divDatos:hover {
    background-color: #0177de;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    &.questions:after {
        content: '\002B';
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        float: right;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
}

La parte de &.questions:after se acabará transformando en .divDatos:hover.questions:after. Pero el elemento con clase divDatos nunca tiene clase questions. questions es un elemento dentro de divDatos por lo que debes añadir un espacio en blanco entre el & y el nombre de la clase: & .questions::after (o directamente eliminar el &). Algo como esto:
.divDatos:hover {
    background-color: #0177de;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    
    & .questions:after {
        content: '\002B';
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        float: right;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
}

Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando:


function hiddeQuestion(element) {
    let e = element;
    let div = document.getElementById("divDatos"+e);
    div.classList.toggle("active");
    let x = document.getElementById("answer"+e);
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
};
.divDatos {
    background-color: #a9d1f4;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #0177de;
    padding:1%;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.divDatos:hover {
    background-color: #0177de;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    
    & .questions:after {
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        float: right;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
}

.questions{
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.questions:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #045dac;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.questions:hover::after {
    color: white !important;
}

.active {
    background-color: #0177de;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}

.active .questions:after {
    content: "\2212";
    color: white;
}

.answers{
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}
<div class="divDatos col-md-12 col-sm-12" id="divDatos1" onclick="hiddeQuestion(1)">
        <span class="questions">
            ¿Pregunta? <!-- <i class="fa-solid fa-user-tie"></i> -->
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="container answers mx-auto" id="answer1" style="display: none !important;">
        <span class="answersText floatLeft col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <P>Respuesta</P>
        </span>
    </div>




Y como te ponía en los comentarios, esto se puede hacer con <details> y <summary> de una manera más simple y sin JS:


.questions {
  background-color: #a9d1f4;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #0177de;
  padding: 1%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.questions::marker { content: ""; }

.questions:hover,
.divDatos[open] .questions {
  background-color: #0177de;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

.questions:after {
  content: '\002B';
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.divDatos[open] .questions:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.divDatos[open]::details-content {
  margin: 1.5rem;
}
<details class="divDatos col-md-12 col-sm-12" id="divDatos1">
  <summary class="questions">
    ¿Pregunta?
  </summary>
  <P>Respuesta</P>
</details>




Como comentario aparte de la respuesta: HTML cuenta con los elementos <details> y <summary> que realizan exactamente lo que quieres sin necesidad de utilizar JavaScript.

Increíble, un mendigo espacio era todo  Pero Alvaro, ahora sucede otra cosa, en su snippet cuando la pregunta está abierta, si se hace hover pone el símbolo +, no sería mejor la regla de .questions:hover::after al final?? Por eso había planteado también esa posibilidad en mi CSS. PD: Si los <details> y <summary> hacer lo que necesito sin JS, no veo porque no pueda cambiarlos, con tal que tengan el efecto deseado lo haré

Para solucionar eso, simplemente elimina el content de los estilos de .questions:hover::after. De ese modo tomará automaticamente el + o el - que tuviera originalmente. He cambiado el código ejecutable para que se vea

@Yenn te puse un ejemplo de como sería usando details/summary al final de la respuesta. Menos HTML, menos CSS y menos JS.

Gracias Alvaro, voy hacer lo que usted sugiere.
